# Why my reputation goes down

Tags: support, reputation

I know there was a recalculation and I know how to track the reputation, but seems it not helps.
My reputation was about 495 just several hours ago and now it goes down to 295. I have checked  there were no down votes.

What can be the issue?

Comment: May be you should add this question to community wiki.

Comment: and why did you tagged this c#...?

Answer (score 4):

When accounts get deleted, all of their votes get deleted as well. If other accounts that had voted your questions and answers up were deleted since your last recalc, you'll lose those votes.  In this case, the first recalc was kicked off by an automated process.  I did the second one myself.

Comment: what you mean I did the second one myself ?

Comment: @Incognito: The second recalculation that caused it to drop to 176.  Moderators can manually trigger a recalculation.

Comment: So you mean that some other accounts have been deleted and as a result clean up was performed. It is very strange, but anyway if this is how it should work ....

Comment: @Incognito: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: So if you get downvoted on your questions or answers you loos reputation, correct?

Comment: @trusktr: Yes, you lose 2 points when someone downvotes your questions or answers, and it costs 1 point to downvote something yourself.

Comment: I felt the same problem. My reputation went down. I don't know the reason why.